# Equivalent of AppConfig.ready() for the whole project?

Tags: python, django

In Django, there is [`AppConfig.ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), which is called when an individual application is ready.

Is there something equivalent for the whole project? How do I know when it's safe to perform operations on few models from different applications?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only *Django notion* of how to load code is the *App* notion, since it is what you can configure in your project settings `INSTALLED_APPS` variable.

To be sure that you can perform operations on those models you should initialize them (its signals, for example) on custom `AppConfig.ready` methods on each of your models apps, and make sure your project includes those models apps in your settings `INSTALLED_APPS` variable.